# Using HTML/PHP forms to access a database and output to the same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a database of schools, I would like to make it so that when you search the database for existing data, it outputs right next the the input box. 
So without going to a new page. 
Here's what a have:

```
<form action=" " method="post">
School's name: <input type="text" name="schoolname"> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
$school      = $_POST['schoolname'];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
mysql_select_db("finalproject");

$sql = "select * from presentations where school like '%$school%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

if ( mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
    {
    while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $school  = $newArray['school'];
        $date = $newArray['date'];
        $place  = $newArray['place'];
        $time = $newArray['time'];


        echo $school . ", " . $place . ", " . $date . ", " . $time . "<br />" ;
        }
    }
    else 
        {
        echo "Record not found";
        }



mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

This is code that I have used previously to link to another page, outputting there.
but now I just want to output it on the same page.
I did move some code over from the other page which no longer seems to be working. 
The PHP bit just outputs:
"0) { while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $school = $newArray['school']; $date = $newArray['date']; $place = $newArray['place']; $time = $newArray['time']; echo $school . ", " . $place . ", " . $date . ", " . $time . "
" ; } } else { echo "Record not found"; } mysql_close($conn); ?>" onto my page below the input.
I'm really new to this, so anyones help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: what problem you are facing to display in a same page?

Comment: Just make sure that `$_POST['schoolname']` `isset` before searching the database.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: And @azizpunjani isn't set already? Through the form?

Comment: Not the first time the page loads. When you submit the form, it is then. The code will run even when the page first loads and `schoolname` is not set.. Do a `var_dump( $_POST )` to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: Right now my PHP is displaying itself past if ( mysql_num_rows($result) >0) So I'm not sure if the problem is from there at this point.

Comment: Check what your `$sql` statement is.  `echo $sql`, what do you get ?

Comment: No matter where I try to place the "echo $sql" it just displays exactly that to my main page. "echo sql"

Comment: Ok, take all php code out and do a simple `<?php echo 'this is a test to see if php is getting parsed' ?>`

Comment: Nothing shows up at all.

Comment: What file extension are you using ? Also are you running it on a server ?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, so yes it is on a server. And it is HTML.

Comment: It needs to be .php so that apache knows it needs to be passed onto the php interpreter. Unless you modified settings explicitly telling apache to parse .html files.

Comment: Alright. So the PHP is working. Its almost perfect. Now only one problem. When first launched it says its undefined for "schoolname" and it just outputs everything. How can I set it before hand? Especially because i have it to even a blank will turn up data.

Comment: Stephen, if you recall i answered that question. Check `isset( $_POST['schoolname'] )` And only if it's set then continue with any php code.

Comment: Where do I put that though? It's php that much i can tell. :/

Comment: Well anyway. I suppose i'll google it. I'll post back my answer. Thank you so much for all your help! @azizpunjani !

Comment: stephan, look at my answer, that's all you need to do. And mark it as answered if it helped you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your file extension is `.php`. Also check if `$_POST['schooname']` `isset` and if it is then continue with php code. A few other pointers, the use of the `mysql` extension is not recommended since it's deprecated. Use either `mysqli` or `PDO`, also santize your input if you must use it. I left the sanitation bit to you.

```
<form action=" " method="post">
School's name: <input type="text" name="schoolname"> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Search">
</form>

<?php

if( isset( $_POST['schoolname'] ) && strlen( trim( $_POST['schoolname'] ) ) > 0  )
{
        $school      = $_POST['schoolname'];

        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        mysql_select_db("finalproject");

        $sql = "select * from presentations where school like '%$school%'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if ( mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
        {
            while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $school  = $newArray['school'];
                $date = $newArray['date'];
                $place  = $newArray['place'];
                $time = $newArray['time'];


                echo $school . ", " . $place . ", " . $date . ", " . $time . "<br />" ;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Record not found";
        }



        mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to make requests to server without page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify this little snippet for the ajax part...It's using jQuery, so you'll need to include the library into your page.

```
$('#submitButtonID').click(function(){

var data = {
    schoolName: $('#schoolName').val()
};
$.ajax({
    url: "PhpPageWithQuery.php",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#resultsDiv).html(msg);

    }
});
```